# app crashes while relaunching after closing it by back button React Native

Tags: react-native

I've developed an android app which is working fine. But when i close the app using hardware back button, then when i try to relaunched it again, it crash. And it is not giving me enough information where i can solve the problem. the error code it generate:

```
com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating's.setState),stack
```

Can anyone help me out with that? Here is my dependencies:

```
"@expo/vector-icons": "^10.2.0",
"@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.10.3",
"@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.4.1",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-native-community/netinfo": "^4.7.0",
"@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.1",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.1",
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.8.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.1",
"native-base": "^2.13.12",
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
"react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
"react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^1.1.0",
"react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
"react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.0.2",
"react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
"react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
"react-native-sqlite-storage": "^5.0.0",
"react-native-sweet-alert": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
"react-native-webview": "^10.2.3"
```

Let me know if you need more informations.

[image: image gif]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVcfG.gif)

[image: stack-trace]

Comment: undefined is not an object (evaluating's.setState), find the `s`.

Comment: @Horst the funny thing is, i am using functional component to all my components and definitely not using any state named s. So not sure it is triggered from my components!

Comment: Stack Trace Error?

Comment: @C.K i don't know how to log that one

Comment: @C.K  i've updated my question, let me know if you are talking about this one

Comment: its clearly shows that you using an undefined object `that.setState`. You have a typo on your source code, Using code editor search for `that.setState` and change into `this.setState`.

Comment: why `that.setState`? is it not `this.setState`?
Could you share your code?

Comment: @C.K i am using functional component. and im pretty sure i did not use it anywhere. I just checked all my components too. none found.

Comment: In class component we update state using `this.setSatate` and you have mistakenly have typed `that.setState` instead of `this.setState`.

Comment: @C.K as i've said. i just checked all my components, i did not even use any word related to setState. Not even one.

Comment: ok, interesting. Can you able to include the error trace after your app crashes.

Comment: I was using class component before, then had to implement context and hook. so replaced all my class component to functional component. So is there any chance that is has cached previous code! Although i did not made the mistake before (i'm pretty sure of that too). <Can you able to include the error trace after your app crashes?> How do i do that!

Comment: What does logcat say?

Comment: You need to share your code for the same file

Comment: @KaranMehta there is lot of code, which part should i share!